# IRandomAccessStream Reference convert to stream reference c#

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

Is there any method or anyway to convert IRandomAccessStreamReference to streamreference using c# in windows 8 metro apps???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, by streamreference, you mean a class inheriting from `Stream`, there is the [`WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.io.windowsruntimestreamextensions.aspx) which adds extension methods so that you can do things like:

```
Stream s = (await myFile.OpenReadAsync()).AsStreamForRead();
```